# Font Awesome not working (blank squares)

Tags: css, fonts, dns, hosting

I was building a website for my wedding, and I hosted it in x10hosting with a .tk domain.
The thing is.. when I access it with x10host.com I`m able to see the fontawesome icons for mobile (menu/go to the top).
When I access it with the .tk extension, the icons are a blank square.

I searched for this same problem here, and tried a bunch of solutions, and none worked for me.

What I`ve tried:

this code in .htacess

```
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(eot|font.css|otf|ttc|ttf|woff)$">
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

this in .style.css

```
@import url("http://karinaandclinton.x10host.com/wp-content/themes/optimizer/assets/fonts/font-awesome.css");
```

this in the header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://karinaandclinton.x10host.com/wp-content/themes/optimizer/assets/fonts/font-awesome.css" type="text/css">
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

changing all the url in fontawesome.css to full address:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('http://karinaandclinton.x10host.com/wp-content/themes/optimizer/assets/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
  src:  /*url('http://karinaandclinton.x10host.com/wp-content/themes/optimizer/assets/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular') format('svg'),*/
  url('http://karinaandclinton.x10host.com/wp-content/themes/optimizer/assets/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
  url('http://karinaandclinton.x10host.com/wp-content/themes/optimizer/assets/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
  url('http://karinaandclinton.x10host.com/wp-content/themes/optimizer/assets/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), 
  url('http://karinaandclinton.x10host.com/wp-content/themes/optimizer/assets/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
```

Does anybody have an extra suggestion?
The website is http://www.karinaandclinton.tk/ and the hosting http://karinaandclinton.x10host.com

The theme I`m using is the Optimizer.

Thank you!

Comment: Not 100% sure why it's not working.  But adding the cdn version `<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">` seems to make it work fine.

Comment: Wishing you both the happily ever after you deserve. Congratulations on your wedding day!

Answer (score 1):

- In urls you should add http://www.karinaandclinton.tk not
  http://karinaandclinton.x10host.com and it should work if you visit
  the 1st url.

OR

- (eot|font.css|otf|ttc|ttf|woff) it should be (eot|css|otf|ttc|ttf|woff)

Comment: Can~t believe I didn`t try that! Thank you so much!

Comment: My Pleasure, @karips ... If this solution worked for you, don't for get to marked it solved.
Many Many Congratulations for your Marriage :)